# Bluetooth Audio Trouble in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, audio, bluetooth

I have been completely unable to connect to any bluetooth headset until following the steps in the first answer in [this forum post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1172000/a2dp-sink-profile-connect-failed):

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
sudo killall pulseaudio
pulseaudio --start    
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

I would prefer to not have to do this after each boot. I am assuming that there is an underlying problem that this set of commands is putting a bandaid over, but I am not sure how to go about diagnosing it.

The original poster of the question said that running these lines to a startup script fix the issue, but I have not had the same luck with them:

```
exec --no-startup-id pactl load-module module-bluetooth-policy
exec --no-startup-id pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

I get `Failure: Module initialization failed` When I attempt to run these commands.

**More about my specific problem:**

After startup, when I try to connect to my bluetooth headphones I immediately get `Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed`.

When running `systemctl status bluetooth` I get:

```
Nov 23 14:31:11 boop bluetoothd[1225]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEMaxConnectionInterval” in group “Controler"
Nov 23 14:31:11 boop bluetoothd[1225]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEConnectionLatency” in group “Controller”
Nov 23 14:31:11 boop bluetoothd[1225]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEConnectionSupervisionTimeout” in group “Controller"
Nov 23 14:31:11 boop bluetoothd[1225]: src/main.c:parse_controller_config() Key file does not have key “LEAutoconnecttimeout” in group “Controller”
Nov 23 14:31:11 boop bluetoothd[1225]: Starting SDP server
Nov 23 14:31:11 boop bluetoothd[1225]: Bluetooth management interface 1.18 initialized
Nov 23 14:31:11 boop bluetoothd[1225]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.168 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov 23 14:31:11 boop bluetoothd[1225]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.168 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov 23 14:31:25 boop bluetoothd[1225]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F4_7D_EF_4F_43_98/sep1/fd0: fd(37) ready
```

Note that along with the previous output I also sometimes get`src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-sink profile connect failed for [device mac address]: Protocol not available`

If I can provide any additional information please ask.

Comment: having the exact same issue. There are some posts on reddit and the arch bbs on this too. Seems to have been caused by a bad update.

Comment: @Brad were you able to fix this issue? If you wouldn't mind linking some of those posts I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: In the end I just downgraded `bluez`, `bluez-libs` and `bluez-utils` from 5.55-1 to 5.54-2.